# Issues loading images using SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I'm loading images for a user's profile using the SDWebImage library. The weird thing is, when I open a profile with lets say, 5 photos, only the last image is showing in the scroll view (full width profile pictures you can scroll through). However, if I close the view and re-open, all the images are there and look perfect. Any idea as to what's going on? Here's the code:

```
func getPhotos(user:PFUser, forKey:NSMutableArray) {

    var p = 0

    for f in forKey {

        if let pic = user.objectForKey(f as! String) as? PFFile {

            var width = Int(phonewidth)
            photoscroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat((p + 1) * width), height: phonewidth)
            pageControl.numberOfPages = p + 1

            var position = CGFloat(p*width)

            var imgview = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(position, 0, phonewidth, phonewidth))



            imgview.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: pic.url), completed: {(image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, cacheType: SDImageCacheType, imageURL: NSURL!) in
                imgview.image = image
                self.photoscroll.addSubview(imgview)
                self.userpics.append(image)
                p++
                println("Added: \(f), URL: \(pic.url)" )
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a break point in your image download completion block. Does the break point ever get hit?

Comment: You mean after incrementing the "p" variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're incrementing p too late, the completion block won't run immediately so your loop is going to have the same value for p every time it runs and your image views will all be stacked on top of each other.

Put the `p++` outside of the block.